# Overwrite field content

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am using this code to put content in a `Field` using Word Interop:

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Path.GetFullPath("myTemplate.dotx"));
Field f = wordDoc.Fields[0];
f.Select();
wordApp.Selection.TypeText("some text");
```

but this works only once. If I run the `f.Select()` statement again, I get a `COMException` telling me the object is gone.

Is there a way to overwrite field content? Or do I have to work with being able to write a `Field` only once?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean when you say that the code only works once.

Comment: @RossBush I tried to clarify: when calling the `f.Select()` code after the `TypeText` part, I get a `COMException`, telling me the object is gone.

Comment: what is return type of f.Select()? and Fields? It might be possible it is Enumerable and you can iterate over it only one. Solution is to save it into list and then work with that list ;)

Comment: @Dan, that seems to be something to live with then. But I also found out all formatting is gone when I replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select the field, and then use `TypeText`, that replaces the whole field with your input text. Instead, you should be using [Field.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834824.aspx) property:

```
f.Result.Text = "some text";
```

Therefore, your code should be something like the following:

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Path.GetFullPath("myTemplate.dotx"));
wordDoc.Fields[1].Result.Text = "some text"; // AFAIK, `Fields` collection is one-based.

// Do whatever other modifications you want, then save and close the document.
```

Hope that helps :)